# Where can I find a list of all available methods of a request object in Django DTL?

Tags: django, django-templates, request

How can I know what methods are used for request object in DTL?

```
 {{ request.WHAT }}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Request objects are defined here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/). In a template you can't invoke functions which require arguments, so only attributes and functions without arguments in there.